# Ember.js view value to controller binding

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Suppose I have a `view` which `this.controller` is `application_controller`, so how can I bind `value` of this view to `another_controller`. View is a `TextField`.

View (there is an application_controller in the context of this view):

```
CellarRails.SearchTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  templatename: 'index',
  insertNewline: function(){
    this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('search');
  }
});
```

Search controller:

```
CellarRails.SearchController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: [],
  query: ''
});
```

Search route (here I grab query property of search controller which I want to bind with view):

```
CellarRails.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serializeParams: function(controller) {
    return {
      query: controller.get('query')
    };
  },
  setupController: function(controller, context, params) {
    console.log(params);
    controller.set('context', CellarRails.Track.find(params));
  }
});
```

Can I extend application controller and add `needs: 'search'` to it, so I could do `this.controller.search.get('query')` to get query property of search controller?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: shure, check out updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have almost answered the question yourself, here is the last bit.

After adding needs you can do:

```
this.get('controllers.search').get('query');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Nikita, as a best practice your view shouldn't know about your controller, but the other way around. Create a computed property on your controller on which your view binds to, and inside the CP you have then access to your controllers.search.query. IMO this would be the way to do it.

Comment: IIRC, the double 'get's aren't necessary.     this.get('controllers.search.query') should also work.

Comment: @JavonHarper thanks for the comment, you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 2):

Just some notes, yes you can extend the application controller and add needs search

```
 CellarRails.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['search'],
    someMethod: function(){
      // this would be the query property from the search controller
      var query = this.get('controllers.search.query');
    }
 });
```

Also, Maybe this portion is working for you, if so ignore me, but I don't believe the setupController hook has 3 parameters.

```
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
       or
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
```

And the model hook is the one that gets the params, and ember passes that to the setup controller

Comment: You're right, I didn't noticed that Im using ember-query library.